# Render ArrayTable java object on jsp in GridFormat

Tags: java

I am trying to find a way to render ArrayTable java object to render on jsp page
in grid format. Does anybody has idea about this. Technology I am working on is struts.

Comment: Please provide the code you have so far.

Comment: Because of code of confidentiality I can't do that but to five you more insight it is related to grid mapper. But my main problem statement is to display data in Array Table efficiently on jsp page.